# Updating Specific column by pressing Update Button C# with Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, c#-4.0

I have made text boxes that when filled will update the relevant database column.
I would like the user to choose the id number from the table by inserting the ID number in a textBox then change username from e.g James to Alex by typing it in a textBox then pressing update button. However i get "Incorrect Syntax near Update Statement" error.

here's my code:

```
protected void unUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var myConnection = GetConnection())
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update staff set username ? where id = ?", myConnection))
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", txt_name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", txt_id.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } myConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: x.x how silly of me...... I get "incorrect syntaxnear update query" @cFrozenDeath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of passing command parameter is not correct.You should do something like this

```
   using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update staff set username = @username where id = @userid", myConnection))
   {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txt_name.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", txt_id.Text);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```